# SpaceVim layer for openning paired parenthesis

Tags: vim, plugins, spacevim

I've been using SpaceVim and loving it. But I've noticed that the default setup doesn't come
shipped with the feature of automatic creation of pairs of parenthesis, brackets, and similar
thing. What I mean is, when I press `(`, I'd like for Vim to automatically create a pair `()` with the cursor inside the parenthesis.

I know that there are some plugins on Vim to do this. But I was wondering if there was a default
layer or configuration available in SpaceVim. Looking at the list of available layers, I was not able to spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial to do yourself:

```
noremap! ( ()<Left>
```